# Как вычисленный MD5 файла сравнить с известным?

Tags: c++, md5

Задача: подтвердить целостность файла в проекте. Для этого вычисляется MD5 файла, далее вычисленное значение подразумевается сравнить с известным значением, и в результате выносится вердикт в виде сообщения ShowMessage. Приведенный фрагмент кода реализует вычисление MD5 и выведение результата (для тестов) на консоль. С этим всё в порядке - отображаемое в консоли значение хэша правильное. Продвинуться же далее до ShowMessage пока не получается. Алгоритм вроде должен быть такой: в буфер заносится массив, вычисляемый в цикле, и далее преобразуется в AnsiString. Реализовать этот пробел в коде не удаётся никак: или ошибки, или AnsiString = NULL.
Прошу помочь.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
    
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

 using namespace std;

 BOOL f = AllocConsole();

 CHAR *FileName = "File.bin";

WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    LPCWSTR filename=L"FileName";

    hFile = CreateFile(FileName,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);

    CryptAcquireContext(&hProv,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        PROV_RSA_FULL,
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);

    CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash);

    while (bResult = ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE, &cbRead, NULL))
     {
       if (cbRead == 0)
        {
          break;
        }
    CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0);
    }

    cbHash = MD5LEN;

    CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0);

        freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        printf("MD5 hash of file %s is: ", FileName);
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
            rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
        }
            printf("\n");

                             // We have added the code for the implementation of the comparison.

           AnsiString AStr;
           if (AStr != "16DF3988591796F39E3D5E947D8039C9")
                 {
                   ShowMessage("FAKE!!!");
                   return 0;
                 }

       system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно просто сравнить две строки. `strcmp`, если строки в C-стиле.

Comment: Если не очень сложно, уточните, пожалуйста, а какие именно две строки? - Весь код перед Вами.

Comment: Не строки кода, а две строки — MD5 хэш, который вы вычислили и MD5 хэш, который вам нужен (`"16DF3988591796F39E3D5E947D8039C9"`, вот этот, я так понимаю).

Comment: Ну т. е. у вас будет что-то типа `if (strcmp(вычисленный_хэш, "16DF3988591796F39E3D5E947D8039C9")) /* Fake */`.

Comment: Дык, строки с вычисленным MD5 хэшем просто нет! Если б она была, то этого топика не было бы. По сути вопрос состоит в том, чтобы её сформировать.

Comment: Вы его выводите на экран? Ну так выводите в строку вместо экрана...

Comment: @ChVL, почему у вас тогда вопрос называется «Как вычисленный MD5 файла сравнить с известным?», а в теле вопроса написано «Приведенный фрагмент кода реализует вычисление MD5»? Определитесь с тем, что у вас есть в коде, а чего нет.

Comment: Проблема в том, что вычисленный хэш не отправляется на экран в готовом виде из какого-то буфера, а формируется в цикле.

Comment: Вот печатается ваш хэш: `printf("%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4], rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);`. Вытащите эти значения и заполните ими какой-нибудь буфер. Или используйте `sprintf` и пишите в строку, а не `stdout`.

Comment: Т. е. у вас хэш уже готов и лежит в `rgbHash`, нужно только правильно из него сформировать строку.

Comment: Или из строки второй rgbHash )

Comment: @ eanmos. В rgbHash лежит какая-то абракадабра из набора 22-х всяких символов и никакими функциями ни во что вразумительное не преобразуется. В том числе в крайне нужную AnsiString. Эти две строки мучал 100500 раз, перекопал весь интернет в поисках аналогов вывода, но пока безрезультатно...

Comment: @ Mikhailo. Все rgbHash везде одинаковые.

Comment: @ChVL, ну у вас же вот вывод: `printf("%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4], rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf])`. Вот, [посмотрите](https://gist.github.com/Eanmos/7e27e633cd12e843fbcda029218ca0ac).

Comment: @**eanmos** Спасибо! Однако не работает - где-то что-то надо допилить. Ошибка принципиальная, ибо buffer = "1d38519f9359783c9\0\0\...0" Всего нулей 16.

Answer (score 0):

@**eanmos** Всё в порядке, допилил. Огромное Вам спасибо за наводку! Основные изменения: функции буфера должны быть такие: buffer[i*2] = (rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4]); и buffer[i*2+1] = (rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]); В результате имеем 100%-но рабочий вариант кода для вычисления MD5 файла, сравнения вычисленного значения с известным и вывод результата сравнения на экран. Может кому в хозяйстве пригодится. Вопрос решён.